# Data structure choice python

Tags: python, data-structures

I have list of around 10,000 elements and for each pair combination of elements from this list I have a number. I need to have all this numbers and combinations in memory to call it by both variants: `comb(a,b)` or `comb(b,a)`.

However, I don't want to duplicate values in dictionary or something like this, because `dict[a][b] = dict[b][a]`. Could you advice me a data structure without duplication?

Comment: maybe a `set` of `frozenset`s? `set(frozenset([a,b,comb(a,b)]), ...)`

Comment: Applying filters to a pandas dataframe should do the trick. http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.18.1/generated/pandas.DataFrame.filter.html

Comment: Can you access combinations using indexes instead of using actual values ? for example if you have list a=[1,2,3,4] then instead of finding comb(2,4) can you use comb(1,3) i.e. the indexes ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest you to go with `frozenset`. More docs:
https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset

So you will have a dict, where frozensets will act as keys(please note that you can't use regular set, since it is mutable and couldn't act as a dictionary key).
Frozenset is unordered, so it perfectly fits your needs. The only limitations is that you can't duplicate elements - **frozenset is unordered sequence of unique elements**.

So your dict will looks like:

```
pairs = {
frozenset(['a', 'b']): 4
....
}
```

And a call `pairs[frozenset(['a', 'b'])]` is equal to `pairs[frozenset(['b', 'a'])]`

UPD: I was really hurry at first, so made a few typos. Fixed them now :)

Answer (score 0):

*Note: I am assuming that the values in the list are unique and you have flexibility to use indexes of actual values (or you are ready to sacrifice time)*

If you really want to save space , i would suggest you to use list of lists to store values for each combination. You do not actually need to store mapping (a,b) -> x.

For example, consider the list:

```
a = [1,2,3,4]
```

Suppose Combinations/value pairs are:

```
(1,2) -> 2, (1,3) -> 3, (1,4) -> 4, (2,3) -> 5, (2,4) -> 6, (3,4) -> 7
```

The storage for combination/value pair will look like:

```
comb_value = [[2,3,4],[5,6],[7]]
```

**Retrieval:**

Assuming that **list a** and **comb_value** are global. (We will dry run the code simultaneously.)

```
# Consider that x=2 and y=4.
def comb(x,y):
   # if you can use index directly, next 2 lines should be skipped.
   x= find_index(x) # Returns 1. 
   y= find_index(y) # Returns 3.
   if x < y :
      return _comb(x,y) # calling _comb(1,3)
   return _comb(y,x)

# x= 1 and y =3
def _comb(x,y):
   return comb_value[x][y-x-1] # returns comb_value[1][3-1] i.e. 6.
```

Answer (score 0):

```
d = {}
d[('a', 'b')] = 12
d[('y', 'z')] = 34
```

and a function to fetch

```
def fetch(a, b):
    return d.get((a, b)) if (a, b) in d else d.get((b, a), None)
```

output:

```
In [16]:
fetch('b', 'a')
Out[16]:
12

In [17]:
fetch('y', 'z')
Out[17]:
34

In [19]:
fetch('z', 'y')
Out[19]:
34

In [20]:
fetch('m', 'n')
```